# Unable to label axis of correlation matrix or cap the figure legend values in R studio?

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation

I am able to plot a correlation matrix of the dataframe 'Object2'.

```
ggcorrplot(object2)
```

However, when I try to extend this function, to cap the figure legend and to label the axis, it does not work:

```
ggcorrplot(object2, aes(x=Coef3,y=Coef4), limits=FALSE)
```

It gives me this:

```
Error in ggcorrplot(object2, aes(x = Coef3, y = Coef4), limits = FALSE) : 
  unused argument (limits = FALSE)
```

Comment: The error indicates that `ggcorrplot` does not have a `limits` argument.

Comment: Also the second argument is `method`, which is `"square" or `"circle"`, so you can't just pass an `aes` mapping there. Please read the documentation at `?ggcorrplot`.